# Combining text fields in a specific way

Tags: fields-attributes, text

I'm sorry for my English.
I look for tool or script for combining text fields in this way:
e.g.

field_1 (contains 3 to 6 signs)

field_2 (contains 6 to 10 signs)

[field_1] & x & [field_2]

where x = variable number of signs (e.g. "-" or "0") which will give me globally always 25 characters as a result of combining.
I'm working in arcgis or qgis. It could be also tool in acces or excel.

Comment: '%s%s' %(!field_1!,!field_2!.zfill(25-len(!Field_1!)-len(!Field_2!)))

Comment: it is python ???

Comment: It is python expression for field calculator in ArcGIS

Comment: !field_1!+!field_2!.zfill(25-len(!field_1!))

Comment: now it seems working :) - thanks for python lesson :)

Comment: OK its definitely working, but how change "0" for any character in this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the total length of the two fields.
Then subtract that number from 25 to get y
Then create a string y characters long.

Create a table, with two columns. 
One column with the count of characters,
One column with a character string y characters long (Field Y)

Then calculate a new field (field 5) as field1+field y+field2.

There are likely better ways to do it, but this should get it done.